How to setup BQ25713 charger via I2C with STM32
I am new and created a special charger PCB. I've checked all datasheets but I could not reach out necessarry information about which codes and registers requires.
I am using BQ25713 charger and STM32F030(HAL). I've registered below values but the BQ25713 charger still doesn't work. What other records and values ​​do I need to run charger? IIN_DPM(), ProchotOption0(), MinSystemVoltage()  etc...
  uint16_t chargeCurrents = SetI2CData(BQ25713_REG_CHARGE_CURRENT, 22);
  (void)chargeCurrents;

  uint16_t chargeOptions = SetI2CData(BQ25713_REG_CHARGE_OPTION_0, 0x020E);
  (void)chargeOptions;

  uint16_t maxVoltages = SetI2CData(BQ25713_REG_MAX_CHARGE_VOLTAGE, 0x20D);
  (void)maxVoltages;


Do your I2C functions work ok? i.e. does the slave device ACK the transaction? You've not really given us much to work with here.
